# mariadb-server-10.1 fails to install on MX Linux

Tags: linux, mysql, mariadb

Trying to install `mysql-server` which requires mariadb.
However, my package manager fails as soon as it gets to `mariadb-server-10.1` with the errors:

```
Setting up mariadb-server-10.1 (10.1.41-0+deb9u1) ...
insserv: warning: script 'K01httpd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: script mysql: service mysql already provided!
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package mariadb-server-10.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u4) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47+b1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mariadb-server-10.1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What can I do to resolve this?